# Parallel algorithm to count the number of leaves in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Let T be a binary tree with $n$ leaves. Let e be an internal edge of T. If we remove e from T then the leaves (L) of tree T are partitioned into two sets L' and L'' respectively. I would like to count the number of vertices in L' and L'' in $O(logn)$ time using polynomial many parallel processors. 
I tried using tree traversal methods but couldn't find the solution.
Note that the input tree is given in the form of adjacency matrix.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the tree represented? Can you find a node's children (and parent) in costant time?

Comment: Tree is represented using adjacency matrix.

Comment: There must be anything more about the "binary tree". We need either (a) a limit on the internal nodes, (b) a statement that every internal node has two children or (c) any kind of balancing condition. With your problem statement, the graph could contain a chain of exponential length which is impossible to count with polynomially many processors.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I assume that every internal node has exactly two children. It would work with other assumptions, but this one is the easiest for showing the principle. Crucially, the assumption must imply that there are polynomially many nodes in total.

By our assumption, we have $N$ nodes in total (N < 2n).

Then take N⁴ processors P(i,j,k,m), (1<=i,j,k<=N) and use them as follows to make the adjacency matrix (containing 1s to mark edges) a subtree size matrix where A(i,j) is the size of j's subtree (if j is a child of i).

A processor P(i,j,k,m) is responsible for updating the value (i,j) if there are edges (j,k) and (j,m), i.e. if j has children k and m.

So processor P(i,j,k,m) checks whether A(i,j)!=0, A(j,k)!=0 and A(j,m)!=0. If this is the case, it adjusts A(i,j)=1+A(j,k)+A(j,m).

There may be race conditions, but as there are not paths of length>N, after at most 2ld(N) rounds, the matrix stabilizes.

Now use your paralell processors to sum the two values in rows of the roots of L' and L'', and you have your numbers.